# 3D surface plot with provided coordinate with PlotlyJS in Julia

Tags: plot, plotly, julia, julia-plots

As stated in the question, I would like to plot a function, `f(x, y)` which is represented in a vector `[x, y, f(x, y)]`. So clearly the `[x, y]` is the desired coordinate.

I looked up in their [official page](https://plotly.com/julia/3d-surface-plots/) and found 3d surface plot can be done as follow:

```
using PlotlyJS, CSV, HTTP, DataFrames
# Read data from a csv
df = CSV.File(
    HTTP.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv").body
) |> DataFrame

z_data = Matrix{Float64}(df)'
(sh_0, sh_1) = size(z_data)

x = range(0, stop=1, length=sh_0)
y = range(0, stop=1, length=sh_1)
layout = Layout(
    title="Mt Bruno Elevation", autosize=false,
    width=500, height=500,
    margin=attr(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90)
)

plot(surface(z=z_data, x=x, y=y), layout)
```

Which the `x` and `y` parameter is just to specify the two axis domain, but not the coordinates of each element in the matrix `z`.

I think these type of plot is really useful and there's no reason it cannot be done.

If there is a way to do this neatly, please educate me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Julia (I'm a Python user), but Plotlyjs is the same on both languages. Surfaces (and contours) requires the function to be evaluated on a rectangular grid domain. For example, let `x=[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2], y=[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]`, the function must be evaluated on point `(-2, -3), (-2, -2), (-2, -1), ..., (-1, -3), (-1, -2), (-1, -1), ..., (0, -3), (0, -2), ...`. The spacing between the grids can be non-uniform. If you have a dataset with sparse points, you can interpolate between x and y coordinates to create a grid and use it with plotly.